# Ambiguous call when a method has overloads for IDictionary and IDictionary<TKey, TValue>

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, overloading, ambiguous

When a method has two overloads, one accepting `IDictionary` and another accepting `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, passing `new Dictionary<string, int>()` to it is considered ambigous. However, if the two overloads are changed to accept `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, the call is no longer ambigous.

As `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements all of the above interfaces (to be precise, `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, `IDictionary`, `ICollection`, `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, `IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, `IEnumerable`, `ISerializable`, `IDeserializationCallback` in .NET 4.5); as `IDictionary` is inherited from `IEnumerable` and `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is inherited from `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, I can't understand why it happens.

Sample console application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AmbigousCall
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            FooDic(dic); // Error: The call is ambiguous
            FooEnum(dic); // OK: The generic method is called
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void FooDic (IDictionary dic) {}
        static void FooDic<TKey, TValue> (IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dic) {}
        static void FooEnum (IEnumerable dic) {}
        static void FooEnum<TKey, TValue> (IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> dic) {}
    }
}
```

The error I get is: *The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'AmbigousCall.Program.FooDic(System.Collections.IDictionary)' and 'AmbigousCall.Program.FooDic(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary)'*

Question 1: Why does it happen?

Question 2: How to accept both generic and non-generic arguments without causing ambiguity if a class implements both?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C# will call the most specific overload available. It has no trouble identifying `IEnumerable<T>` as more specific than `IEnumerable` because `IEnumerable<T>` extends `IEnumerable`. However, `IDictionary<T, U>` does *not* extend `IDictionary`, so even though `Dictionary<T, U>` implements both, the compiler cannot identify which is more specific. To the compiler, these might as well be completely unrelated interfaces.

You'd have to give the compiler a hint by using an explicit cast:

```
FooDic((IDictionary)dic); // not ambiguous
FooDic((IDictionary<string, int>)dic); // not ambiguous
```

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that `IEnumerable<T>` inherits `IEnumerable`, whereas `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not inherit `IDictionary`.

As a result, resolving between overloads that accept `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable` is a simple matter of determining whether the argument matches the more specific or the more general version, whereas resolving between `IDictionary` and `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is impossible because the two interfaces are not related.

If you have overloads that accept `IDictionary` and `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, you'll have to cast your argument to the type you want:

```
FooDic((IDictionary)value);
```

or

```
FooDic((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)value);
```